# User agent based output by Drupal CMS/

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I need to develop an online service layer that will provide multi-role interactivity to end users on the behalf user agent/device/application (desktop or web widget) or output type (XML) they use.

So...

- How is drupal as choice?
- Is it possible to develop output
  templates for each output type
  required?
- How to switch theme or output mode on
  the behalf of user agent?

Comment: Perpahs this helps a little more : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53705/redirect-to-mobile-page-not-theme-switching

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [services module](http://drupal.org/project/services) may do some of what you want in terms of providing a service.

In terms of switching the theme based on the user agent, try [Browscap](http://drupal.org/project/browscap) in conjunction with [Switch Theme](http://drupal.org/project/switchtheme).